# finding more than one root for a set of trigonometric equations: python

Tags: python, trigonometry, equation, equation-solving

I am using python's fsolve to find roots of a set of equations using the script below:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import math
import numpy as np
#from mpldatacursor import datacursor

%pylab
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline


def equations(p):
    x,y,z = p
    f1 = (1 - 2*math.cos(math.radians(x)) + 2*math.cos(math.radians(y)) - 2*math.cos(math.radians(z)) + 0.8)
    f2 = (1 - 2*math.cos(math.radians(5*x)) + 2*math.cos(math.radians(5*y)) - 2*math.cos(math.radians(5*z)))
    f3 = (1 - 2*math.cos(math.radians(7*x)) + 2*math.cos(math.radians(7*y)) - 2*math.cos(math.radians(7*z)))
    return (f1,f2,f3)

x,y,z = fsolve(equations,(0,0,0))
#print equations((x,y,z))
```

This works perfect with one small issue. This generates only one set of solution i.e., one value for each x, y, z to satisfy those equations, but since these are trigonometric there should be atleast 2 solutions. How can I use fsolve (or anything else) to find two solutions for x, y, z  for a given starting point.

Example: for `x,y,z = fsolve(equations,(0,0,0))`, is it possible to generate two values for `x,y,z` instead of one solution?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Isn't this going to have an infinite number of solutions (at the very least `+ 2π*n` for every integer `n`)? So… did you want to get back an infinite number of results?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, you are right. What I am trying to get is the nearest solution on both sides of the axis. `fsolve` generates nearest (one) solution based on the initial value and I think it solves in a uni-directional way. So for example for `0,0,0` initial values say it generates `x,y,z` but instead I also want to generate its counterpart, so I am looking to get something like `x1,y1,z1` and `x2,y2,z2`...

Another way to say it is: I want to find solutions of x,y,z in range of `[0 to 2π]` (one cycle) for a given initial value of `0,0,0`